# Is there a way to get the Flow Error Emails via API?

Tags: visual-workflow

For the Flow error emails that you get when a Flow process fails, is there any way to pull these notifications via an API?

Answer (score 0):

If the flow fails, a detailed email is sent to the administrator who changed the last flow. However, sometimes the admin isn’t the best person to work out the details of what was executed and what went wrong. In that case, you can send an error email to an Apex exception email recipient.

There is no such way to pull the notifications via an API.

[image]

For more detail please refer to the link
[Select Flow and Process Error Email Recipients](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5)